# Z-value from database? QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry

I have a merged shapefile with line geometry. Every line has a Z value written in the database. I want to write this value from the database to the geometry as Z-value.

The basefiles are S-57 DEPCTN layers merged together using vectormerge in QGIS. The Z value is stated in the column [VALDCO]. I want this value in the geometry as Z value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.0 and above you can directly run the "Set Z Value" algorithm from the processing toolbox, and set the geometry's z value using a column in your table.

Answer (score 1):

@CaptainAhab do you have Z-value for each vertex of the line or one for the whole line? And do you want to do the processing on the shapefiles or database?

If you have shapefiles and only one Z-value for whole line there is a quick fix - you can utilize `ogr2ogr` from [GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). Open [OSGeo4W Shell](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (you should have it installed with QGis) and use below command - change the paths to your files and name of the column with z-value:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/lines.shp C:/newlines.shp -zfield column-name-with-z-value
```